# PHP Поиск в БД MySQL

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

**Из БД нужно осуществить поиск имени и фамилии.**

как лучше будет осуществить поиск? 
Что бы Фамилия и Имя были в одном столбе, или в разных?

запросы могут быть такими: *"Имя Фамилия", "Фамилия Имя", "Имя", "Фамилия".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В разных, если нет особых причин для этого. 
Почитайте про [нормализацию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CD%EE%F0%EC%E0%EB%FC%ED%E0%FF_%F4%EE%F0%EC%E0).